# Create general validation using variables

Tags: vba, excel

I want to create a validation rule using VBA. The validation object can be coded in following pattern (for example, add new validation List, ):

```
.add type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="= Sheet1!D3:D5"
```

I wondering if I can assign:

```
type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="= Sheet1!D3:D5"
```

To a variable like this:

```
validationString = " type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=" & chr(35) & "= Sheet1!D3:D5" & chr(35)
```

The variable `validationString` looks like parameter of the coding.  I tried but I got return like type mismatch warning.

Anyone have any experience in this?

Answer (score 0):

Each of the commas separates an individual parameter for the Add() method. You CANNOT combine these into a single string variable to be passed to the Add() method.